What are ways to reduce EMI on my oscilloscope?
Scope in use: Siglent SDS 1104X-E
Small background of what I have going on and what I need to accomplish:
I have devices that sit very close to ignition transformers (Input 120VAC, Output 7000V @ 30mA.) The high side of the transformer discharges directly to the industrial furnaces burner. The output is very inconsistent making it a great noise generator.
I need to scope a few lines on my device while the igniter is firing but when I do there's a ton of noise on the scope. I have reason to believe that it's garbage for the most part but I want to confirm.
Are there any common practices that would help reduce these unwanted inputs so I can get an accurate reading? I placed a Fluke on the line in parallel and put it in the maximum mode and the Fluke never picked up the large amplitudes I was seeing on the scope.



how do you know that what your scope is showing you is not also visible to the circuit your are trying to diagnose?

Are you using the ground clip or "spring" that came with the probe?

I'm confused? This sounds like you are trying to measure reality, which seems to include these spikes. Am I misled?

I don't know what your Fluke is, that's a company that produces a pretty large range of measurement devices, but assuming it's a multimeter: that's going to be very bandwidth-limited, i.e., it doesn't show you things that happen fast, by design. Your oscilloscope, on the other hand, is more expensive, exactly because it lets you see what really happens (up to much higher frequencies).

Are you saying that the ignition transformers seem to be causing problems in the devices, and you are trying to find out if that is actually the case?

I currently don't know, I'm tracking it down, the reason I believe its not is because these spikes exceed the limitations of the devices input and the data looks good with only a minor hiccup occasionally. I'd expect degradation and death of the IC with what i'm seeing.
@SimonFitch Currently using the clip but I will try to reduce the loop with the spring and see.
You may be right and it's real. But how can you know for sure!  Apologies, Fluke-87-V, and yeah I get it.
I am seeing side effects on the device while there is ignition.

@ErricDiFilippo Is it possible to move the devices which are being affected by the ignition transformers to somewhere that they will not be affected? That could include adding appropriate shielding between the item causing the problem and the item being affected.

You also have to realize that these kind of cheap Chinese scopes are cheap for a reason: the quality is subpar at best.

@ErricDiFilippo Could the light that's being measured be transferred some way away, maybe with fibre optics?

The E-field in kV/m and the arc avalanche time are    extreme cases of EMI spanning DC to microwave.  A battery operated floating measurement device makes good sense. To transfer a low voltage signal in that environment requires good balance, low impedance and the best UHF coax.

If you can buffer the impedance of the signal down to 50 ohms to match coaxial cables and terminate at the scope in 50 Ohms is one method that works. But coax quality makes a difference in shielding.

You'll get better results with a Tek FET Diff probe.

If not avail. you can try two matched 200MHz+ 10:1 probes with Ch 1-2 mode.

test the probe cables together to the scope to calibrate immunity during a transient. Probe any dynamic test point together for a flatline on max sensitivity.

This requires that the cables be orthogonal to the transient e-field for best immunity.

If your signal is below 20MHz, also enable the DSO filter.

Add large toroid C-clamps around the probe cable to raise the Zcm transfer impedance

Keep your probe ground leads short to avoid probe resonance on logic transitions.


Choose any method that works and report back when you succeed.
Au contraire
If you simply, want to measure the arc event, take any probe with a long ground clip and short the tip.  This will tell you how much ingress you can expect near the offender zone or the victim zone.  If your circuit is getting unintended behavior, you will need to look at using capacitive feedthrus, ferrite beads, discrete LPF, twisted pair and single-ended shielded STP cable.

I reduced the ground loop on my 100MHz 10:1 probe, this is all I have on hand currently, the amplitudes were reduced quite a bit but still present. I have added two screen captures. The first is the floating input voltage pin measuring across the sense resistor of an ADC, the second picture is a capture of the device with the sensor plugged in, in normal operation. While all of your input is valid I am very ignorant to these practices, my experience scoping is very "on the surface" but I am trying to learn more.

1st plot has 100 MHz resonance, 2nd plot has the crosstalk induced that you are trying to reject?. (with some resonance still included)  Did you try the coil spring method? with no tip & clip.  You may also need a Faraday cage.

Can you explain how you deduced both the 100 MHz resonance and crosstalk? The signal line is 4-20mA and should be relatively stable at the time of ignition. I guess it's worth mentioning that the "Sensor" that has the 4-20mA output is used for sensing ignition, there's essentially a clamp around the ignition wire and we are monitoring the lumens of a gas tube from the emissions of the high voltage fields. Currently the signal cable is shielded on the sensor end but not on the host device due to it being an older pcb revision and not including the extra shield pin.

There may be more than one source of resonance with more information given. This describes probe resonance https://www.tek.com/en/documents/application-note/how-oscilloscope-probes-affect-your-measurement  ESL is your ground path in nH/mm and C is your probe cable in pF/fcm with low Dk cables ~ 60pF/m (?). this will apply to your optical sensor too. (PD+TIA?)  You will want to modify the shield termination and add ferrite clamps. or torroid.  This sensor impedance may be too high. Consider a 6 deg PD sensor used remotely or a lower burden R. or measure AC flame current (?) and limit BW.

Avalanche arc times can be picoseconds while gas ionization times ~1us depending on gas mix, pressure etc.  But flame heat depends on wavelength and brightness is more significant measured in longer time intervals. So I see a capture accuracy issue and stress issues on semiconductor PIV.  One additional solution is to clamp the sensor with a TVS after proper shielding and filtering to suppress any over-voltage risk.  But start by calibrating your scope probe with a 10 ns pulse gen. to get null ringing. Then filter the arc noise to capture the BW of your signal.

Focus on understanding the spectrum and amplitude of Noise 7kV discharged and the bandwidth of the optical signal to determine what SNR is acceptable and how much attenuation is required. This may include a combination of low and hi-f ferrites to span the upper range. The ionization is a random 3D current when it is non-repetitive.

Is there any H2 enriched fuel involved? Then ionization latency and detection time is a critical function.

Just to clarify the use case, the measurement tool in this case is a photoresistor that sits under a neon gas tube. The photoresistor changes the output voltage that is being fed to an IC that takes input voltage and converts it to a 4-20mA signal. The neon gas tube is touching the insulation of the ignition wire with an aluminum extension, the other side of the gas tube is grounded through my data acquisition device. Currently the sensor side and cable are unshielded. I've found that the noise is real that i'm seeing induced on the signal line. It's the first capture, pulses 120Hz apart.

While your input is great i'm having a hard time understanding, you are leagues ahead of me in this field. Now that I know what the noise looks like i'm first going to shield the cable and see what my results are. Lets assume it doesn't change anything or only reduces it. You are mentioning adding ferrite, is this something that you would put in series with the signal line? Does it need terminated on both ends in a specific way? How do I go about selecting the type of ferrite and what values i'd need?

Ferrite examples here. https://palomar-engineers.com/ferrite-products/snap-on-split-beads/All-Ferrite-Ring-Toroid-Cores-c21444154 Read specs and get something that works 10 to `100 MHz and try the other things I said. If it is important, hire a consultant.
